# Как увидеть цвет?

Tags: color, android, java

Нашел в коде 2 цвета,никак не могу их увидеть 0x00FFFFFF и 0x55000000 color picker не помогает, не подскажите как их посмотреть, может быть код цвета не целиком нужно вбивать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x00FFFFFF - полностью прозрачный белый цвет - вы его не увидите

0x55000000 - чуть чуть видимый серый цвет - вы увидите только затенение над тем где этот цвет лежит

Answer (score 4):

Просто так это не увидеть. В данном случае нужно понимать, что такое [альфаканал](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB).
Если элемент с цветом 0x00FFFFFF наложить  на другой, то элемент снизу будет "просвечиваться". Так что цвет у верхнего элемента будет такой же, как и у нижнего.

Если элемент с цветом 0x55000000 наложить на другой, то он затемнит на треть нижележащий.

Формула складывания цвета простая - результирующий цвет = фон * (1-альфаканал) + передний_цвет * альфаканал. альфаканал используется у накладываемого пискеля. Так как обычно альфаканал равен 0xFF, то накладываемый пиксель закрывает собой нижний.

```
табличка:
0xFF = 1
0x80 = 0.5
0x55 = 0.33 (1/3).
0x00 = 0
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понятнее!